# Is there any library for showing firestore data analytics to user in my android app?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, analytics

I'm able to fetch collections and documents from Firestore using query but I want to prepare a dashboard and show analytics to the user.

but query individual collections and then showing relevant data is so tedious to do.

Ex:

I have 100 product each product has some minimum quantity and also I want to show total revenue and most sold product in today, week and month, etc.

Querying different collections and combining above like data is not easy so I want to know is there any library for that which track this data and we will able to fetch easily?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you know that you should not ask for a lirary here, right?

Comment: No, can you suggest anything else apart from library?

Comment: I honestly see no problems to iterate through results to match data

Comment: Okay, waiting for more responses.